# Tensorflow flags not recognized

Tags: python, tensorflow, pyspark

I have a tensorflow code to be run on pyspark.
Code

```
tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("evaluate_every", 100, "Evaluate model on dev set after this man

    y steps (default: 100)")
    tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("window_size", 3, "n-gram")
    tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("sequence_length", 204, "max tokens b/w entities")
    tf.flags.DEFINE_integer("K", 4, "K-fold cross validation")
    tf.flags.DEFINE_float("early_threshold", 0.5, "Threshold to stop the training")

FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
FLAGS._parse_flags()
```

I have a RDD for which I am calling a function `get_input()`. But I am not able to print the **FLAGS** value.

```
def get_input(row):
    FLAGS = tf.flags.FLAGS
    print(FLAGS.__flags)
```

However I get a following error.

```
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 98, in main
    command = pickleSer._read_with_length(infile)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 164, in _read_with_length
    return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 419, in loads
    return pickle.loads(obj, encoding=encoding)
  File "/home/sahil/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/flags.py", line 47, in __getattr__
    if not self.__dict__['__parsed']:
KeyError: '__parsed'
```

Moreover I am not able to create a broadcast variable of a tensorflow object.

For example, if I write

```
ones = tf.ones([2,3])
ones = sc.broadcast(ones)
```

I get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Get the latest TensorFlow (>1.4) with Python3 and use `FLAGS(sys.argv)`, since the `FLAGS._parse_flags()` is not supported any more.

```
import sys
import tensorflow as tf

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS
unparsed = FLAGS(sys.argv)
```